# Correct SQL table alias syntax in trigger with if statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

So basically I'm trying to create a trigger that will update another table if an insert or update is located less than 1 meter of distance of an existing one.

It does not allow me to insert anything because the FROM clause is missing on the if statement and I'm not sure how to call it properly.

I got the following

```
 CREATE TRIGGER access_node_aiu
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON schemab.table
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE schemab.trigegr();

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemab.trigger()
 RETURNS trigger AS
 $BODY$
BEGIN

    if st_distance(new.geom, a.geom) < 1 then
INSERT INTO schemab.overlap
SELECT nextval('schemab.overlap_id_seq'::regclass), a.node_id, new.node_id, a.date, now(), st_distance(a.geom, new.geom), new.geom
FROM schemab.table a;
end if;

    RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;
```

How to do this in postgresql?

Comment: Why not change that `IF` into `WHERE`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I got ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"

Comment: I have posted my answer with syntax that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change IF into WHERE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemab.trigger()
 RETURNS trigger AS
 $BODY$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO schemab.overlap
SELECT nextval('schemab.overlap_id_seq'::regclass), a.node_id, new.node_id, a.date, now(), st_distance(a.geom, new.geom), new.geom
FROM schemab.table a
WHERE st_distance(new.geom, a.geom) < 1;

    RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;
```